# Finding $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^4}\Big(\frac{6}{6+x^2}-\frac{x}{\sinh(x)}\Big)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^4}\Big(\frac{6}{6+x^2}-\frac{x}{\sinh(x)}\Big).$$

I realise we could write this as one fraction and apply L'Hospital a lot of times, but this is very tedious. There ought to be a more elegant way of evaluating this (Possibly using the series expansion of $\sin(x)$?). Some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the Taylor series:

$$\frac{1}{x^4}\Big(\frac{6}{6+x^2}-\frac{x}{\sinh(x)}\Big)\sim_0\frac1{x^4}\frac{6\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}\right)-6x-x^3}{6x}\sim_0\frac{1}{120}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, but using the Taylor expansion of Claude Leibovici, I get $\frac{1}{x^4}\Big(\frac{6}{6+x^2}-\frac{x}{\sinh(x)}\Big) \sim_0 \frac{1}{x^4}\frac{x^4}{120} = 1/120$. I don't understand your first step, do you mind elaborating?

Comment: I wrote the expression on this form before using Taylor:
$$\frac{1}{x^4}\Big(\frac{6}{6+x^2}-\frac{x}{\sinh(x)}\Big)=\frac1{x^4}\frac{6 \sinh(x)-x(6+x^2)}{(6+x^2)\sinh(x)}$$

Comment: Thank you, sir. Sorry for the follow up questions, but shouldn't the limit be $\frac{1}{5!}$ instead of $\frac{10}{3}$ then? Also, how did you arrive at the denominator $6x$?

Comment: On the denominator we have
$$x^4(6+x^2)\sinh(x)\sim_0 x^4\times 6\times x=6x^5$$
and on the numerator after simplification it remains $\frac{6x^5}{5!}$ so the final result is $\frac{1}{120}$ and you're right!.

Comment: Ok, nice. For the numerator we use the approximation $\sinh(x) \sim_0 x + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}$, and for the denominator $\sinh(x) \sim_0 x$. Could you please explain this further?

Comment: You ask the very important issue for the use of taylor series! why I used one time 
$$\sinh(x)\sim_0 x+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}$$ and second time I just write
$$\sinh(x)\sim_0 x$$
and the answer is simple: when we have in the expression *(as in the numerator)* a sum or difference of terms we write the Taylor series until to get a non zero term so in our case for the numerator we should reach to the term on $x^5$.

Comment: Fantastic answer, merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the simplest will be to use Taylor series built around $x=0$. You will find that $$\frac{6}{6+x^2}=1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{36}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ The second one is slightly more tedious but $$\frac{x}{\sinh(x)}=1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{7 x^4}{360}+O\left(x^5\right)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer.